# jquery plugin for auto-paginating search results, with sorting

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I feel like there's a nicer name for this that i don't know, but i'm looking for a plugin that gives you a page worth of results in a container, with ajax, and when you scroll the container down to the bottom of the results (or near the bottom) it makes another call to get page 2 of the results, and appends them to the bottom of the list, etc etc, so that rather than clicking on a link saying "Page 2", "Page 3" etc, you scroll down and it automatically fills them in.

I've got the back end which works with a regular paginated search (non-ajax), with extra params for sort column and order, so just looking for something to plug into that.  Probably wouldn't be too hard to write but i'm lazy and i'm sure someone's done it :)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called endless paging, there are a few plugins:
http://www.webdeveloperjuice.com/2012/05/26/10-aggressively-used-jquery-infinite-scroll-plugins-for-endless-paging/

Just googled it, have nothing to do with that page xD